# ImageField, error: "No se encuentra el archivo asociado"

Tags: django, python-3.7

No se visualiza la imagen en la plantilla, en la etiqueta img. La documentación de django es muy pobre en este tema. También he seguido algunos tutoriales, pero tampoco funciona. El resto de la aplicación funciona perfectamente, sólo me queda arreglar esto. Este es mi proyecto:
Estructura de las carpetas static y media:

```
├───.settings
├───catalogo
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───media
│   └───fotos
│       ├───articulos
│       └───libros
├───plantillas
│   ├───catalogo
│   └───registration
├───static
│   ├───admin
│   │   ├───css
│   │   │   └───vendor
│   │   │       └───select2
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───img
│   │   │   └───gis
│   │   └───js
│   │       ├───admin
│   │       └───vendor
│   │           ├───jquery
│   │           ├───select2
│   │           │   └───i18n
│   │           └───xregexp
│   ├───css
│   ├───js
│   └───media
```

Settings del proyecto:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Modelos:

```
    class FotoArt(models.Model):
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='fotos/articulos/', 
        null=True, blank=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['nombre']
            verbose_name = _('Foto Artículo')
            verbose_name_plural = _('Fotos Artículos')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.nombre

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('detalle-fotoArt', args= 
            [str(self.id)])

    class ArtMixin(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            abstract = True
            ordering = ["titulo"]

        AÑO_CHOICES = []
        for r in range(1975, (datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
            AÑO_CHOICES.append((r,r))

        NORMAL = 'NR'
        BUENO = 'BN'
        NUEVO = 'NV'
        ESTADO_CHOICES = [
            (NORMAL, 'Normal, con señales de uso'),
            (BUENO, 'Buen estado, como nuevo'),
            (NUEVO, 'Nuevo'),
        ]

        titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        precio = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
        estado = models.CharField(
            max_length = 2,
            choices = ESTADO_CHOICES,
            default = BUENO,
        )
        publicado_URLs = models.ManyToManyField(Publicacion, 
        blank=True)
        descripcion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


        def __str__(self):
            return self.titulo

    class Articulo(ArtMixin):
        año_compra = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices = 
        ArtMixin.AÑO_CHOICES)
        fotos = models.ManyToManyField(FotoArt, blank=True)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _('Artículo')
            verbose_name_plural = _('Artículos')

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('detalle-art', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Las vistas:

```
class DetalleFotoArt(generic.DetailView):
    model = FotoArt
    context_object_name = "fotoArt"
    template_name = 'catalogo/detalle_fotoArt.html'

class FotoArtCrear(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = FotoArt
    fields = '__all__'
```

Las plantillas:

```
detalle_fotoArt.html
{% extends 'catalogo/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Foto Artículo: {{ fotoArt.nombre }}</h1>
    <hr/>
    <img src="{{ fotoArt.foto.url}}" alt="{{ fotoArt.nombre }}" height="200" width="200">
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <a class="nav-link btn-style" href = "{% url 'actualizar-fotoArt' fotoArt.pk %}">Actualizar</a>
        <a class="nav-link btn-style" href = "{% url 'borrar-fotoArt' fotoArt.pk %}">Borrar</a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

fotoArt_form.html
{% extends 'catalogo/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Crear/Actualizar Fotos Artículos</h2>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

En la introducción de fotos nuevas (fotoArt_form.html) lanza el error "El atributo 'foto' no tiene ningún archivo asociado.", aunque realmente crea el registro en la base de datos, pero con el campo foto vacío, consultado desde PgAdmin:

[image: PgAdmin: FotoArt]

Y en la consulta de la foto a través de detalle_fotoArt.html, me lanza el mismo error. 
No he introducido ninguna url para controlar las fotos porque no la necesito, pero por si acaso también he probado insertar una:

```
re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

y en el runserver ya lanza este error:

```
File "E:\Trastero\Trastero\urls.py", line 33, in <module>
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\Envs\gelaDjango22\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

¿Qué es lo que está mal? He probado mil cosas, y eso que dicen de que Django es un framework para crear aplicaciones "rápidamente", jajaja me da la risa, seguro que se refiere a los expertos.
También he probado con src= "{{ fotoArt.foto.path}}" y con el mismo error.

Comment: Si, la verás en la estructura del proyecto como media/fotos/articulos.

Comment: Creo que el problema es de subir y mostrar imágenes. Se crea el registro en la BD, pero no en la carpeta media/fotos/articulos. Es decir, que el primer problema, conlleva al otro. Si no se suben bien, es lógico que no las encuentre después.

Comment: vi un error en la linea `<form action="" method="post">` cuando subes archivos debes agregar a tu form `<form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data>`

Comment: Ahora ya no da error cuando subo una foto, pero sigue sin visualizarla. En la BD creó el registro correctamente con el campo foto con el path correcto: fotos/articulos/foto-01.jpg. ¿Está bien en la plantilla: img src="{{ fotoArt.foto.url}}" ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98370/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-frank-mascarell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en tu código los enumero y explico a continuación:

1. Cuando trabajas con archivos en los formulario debe contener el [`enctype='multipart/form-data'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype).
2. La carpeta **`media`** debe ir en la raíz del proyecto, para poder ser visualizada por los distintos módulos de tu aplicación (puedes ver en tu `settings.py` que la ubicastes en la `raiz/media/` observa `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`)
3. en **`Django`** para que se puedean acceder a las carpetas debes agregar la carpeta estatica a `urls.py`; hicistes toda la configuracion y te falto este paso.

---

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static, staticfiles_urlpatterns

# todo tu codigo y al final:

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Genial, funcionó corrigiendo estos errores. Gracias JackNavaRow.